# "Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection (id: 1): [AxiosError: Network Error]" in React Native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, axios

Even though my API key and password are correct, I get this error when I request data via Yelp in React Native. Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection (id: 1): [AxiosError:] Network Error

Can someone help me? Thanks :)

Below is the page with the URL and Authorization of the data I want to call with Axios.

```
import axios from 'axios';

export default axios.create({
  baseURL: 'https://api.yelp.com/v3/businesses',
  headers: {
    Authorization:
      'Bearer aETOPuVSQ-luGy16YjLMitcWYtZh442JZA2f2UPY0ve9r7XDLnrlfVrbVqqJ-MagxP1AugW2wZgFVw2cl2ci8tq0UnFZRzUsT7_x_0-7hVa4F-RZHYx',
  },
});
```

Here I called data

```
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import yelp from '../api/yelp';

export default () => {
  const [results, setResults] = useState([]);
  const searchApi = async (searchTerm) => {
    const response = await yelp.get('/search', {
      params: {
        limit: 50,
        term: searchTerm,
        location: 'Ankara',
      },
    });
    setResults(response.data.businesses);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    searchApi('Kebap');
  }, []);

  return [searchApi, results];
};
```

I print the data on this page with a subcomponent.

```
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from "react-native";
import React from "react";
import SearchBar from "../components/SearchBar";
import useResults from "../hooks/useResults";
import ResultsList from "../components/ResultsList";

export default function SearchScreen() {
  const [searchApi, results] = useResults();
  console.log(results);

  const filterResultsByPrice = (price) => {
    return results.filter((results) => {
      return results.price === price;
    });
  };

  return (
    <View>
      <SearchBar />
      <ResultsList
        title="Cheapst Restaurants"
        results={filterResultsByPrice("₺")}
      />
      <ResultsList
        title="Normal Restaurants"
        results={filterResultsByPrice("₺₺")}
      />
      <ResultsList
        title="Expensive Restaurants"
        results={filterResultsByPrice("₺₺₺")}
      />
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({});
```

Comment: Network error would imply it's not authentication. Try examining the error itself and see what it says.

Comment: @VLAZ - I authenticated. Because I can see the data in YELP and Postman with my own API Authorization. But I cannot call data with console.log